# BottomNavigationView - selected item's text color

Tags: android, menuitem, textcolor, bottomnavigationview

I try to set the text color of the bottom navigation item. [This guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int)) says that there is a function named `setSelectedItemId` sets selected item programmatically. But it required 25.3.0 support library and I use 25.0.0. So I use below code to set selected item:

```
Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
menu.getItem(selectedIndex).setChecked(true);
menu.getItem(currentIndex).setChecked(false);
currentIndex = selectedIndex;
```

My color setting is here :

```
        int[] colors = new int[] {
                Color.BLACK,
                Color.GREEN,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.RED
        };
        int [][] states = new int [][]{
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled, -android.R.attr.state_pressed, -android.R.attr.state_selected}, // enabled
                new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_selected}, // selected
                new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
        };
        bottomNavigationView.setItemTextColor(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```

I cannot see selected text color. Item text color is RED when I press the item. I expect that the item text color will be BLUE after pressing(because I think it's state is selected.)

Comment: I highly recommend you to use a 3rd party lib for this view, there were a lot of bugs when i used it first(5 months ago maybe).

Comment: @hcknl it is not possible yet :) I must use bottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me. However in my situation I am only using two colors. 
but basically the

> android.R.attr.state_pressed

only sets the color while pressing

> android.R.attr.state_checked

will set the color after you stop pressing the button.

```
int[] colors = new int[] {
    Color.BLACK,
    Color.GREEN,
};

int [][] states = new int [][]{
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled, -android.R.attr.state_checked},
    new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_checked}
};

bottomNavigation.setItemTextColor(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
bottomNavigation.setItemIconTintList(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
```